# Customized the Suggestion List of AutoComplete Text View

Tags: android, android-layout, autocomplete, customization

This is the code for my AutoCompleteTextView :

```
    String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries_array);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.item_list ,countries);
    textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
          textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is item_list :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textColor="#000"
 android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow">
```

and this is the output :

[image]

I want to change this pop-up kind of suggestion box , and want to show the suggestion list a little bit below from the AutoCompleteTextView ..similar to this : (please disregard the apple design, it’s just about where the results appear)

[image]

How can i do this ..Please suggest .
Thanks.!!

Comment: can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046302/how-to-implement-autocompletetextview-with-listview

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `android:dropDownAnchor`, `android:dropDownHorizontalOffset`, `android:dropDownVerticalOffset` and maybe others on the `AutoCompleteTextView` in your layout. See [AutocompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

Answer (score 9):

I used a ListView below the AutoCompleteTextView. I added my custom adapter to both the ListView and the AutoCompleteTextView. I the set the height and width of the AutoCompleteTextView dropdown to 0:

```
myListView.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
myAutoComplete.setAdapter(myCustomAdapter);
myAutoComplete.setDropDownHeight(0);
myAutoComplete.setDropDownWidth(0);
```

Since the listview is also attached to the same adapter it'll get updated when you update the autocomplete.

Comment: I think I'll go for this too.. I can't find other solution. :/

Comment: can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046302/how-to-implement-autocompletetextview-with-listview

Answer (score 0):

u need QSB (Quick search box).
refer to this http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/qsb.html

It needs a ContentProvider to fill the QSB data.